# Examples for nodejs client for AWS REST API without SDK

Tags: node.js, rest, amazon-web-services

For a variety of reasons, I cannot use the AWS javascript SDK for nodejs for the various AWS services. I would like to use the AWS REST API instead, where I have to make the HTTP request calls to the endpoints and handle HTTP responses, errors etc.

Is there an example somewhere that shows how I can do this? I am aware of basic REST API programming for clients, but would appreciate examples anyway. Not everyone is able to use the SDK owing to the fact that the profile of the customer client requests may always not be known to be a particular AWS service/request.

FWIW, there is little to no information on the documentation for AWS for this (there is information on the REST API endpoints themselves, but not much else).

Comment: fwiw - similar lib ... https://github.com/sekka1/AWS-REST-API-Server

Comment: *"there is little to no information on the documentation..."*  There is a substantial amount of official documentation on how to create API requests. See, for example, the [EC2 API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/Query-Requests.html)... as well as how to authenticate by [signing requests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html).  *"Not everyone is able to use the SDK owing to the fact that the profile of the customer client requests may always not be known to be a particular AWS service/request."*  I don't understand this comment.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, agreed re: info signing requests etc. Also very familiar with all the SDK pages. My OP has to do with a page of *examples* showing how to do how I can handle a lower level API call. I cannot go into the details of my operation, but as an example, I am not able to ascertain in my application whether the user will ask for `iam.listUsers ()` or `s3.listBuckets ()` beforehand (using the node API here). Moreover, I don't want to build out a giant `case/switch` statement that covers all possible API calls.

Comment: The link I mentioned to the EC2 API Reference is an example of exactly what you just asked for -- the low level API call structure... but what you seem to be asking for is (I assume) based on a lack of understanding of something, somewhere, because accessing the low-level is far, far more complex than using the SDKs, the point of which is to abstract away some of the complexity.  You will need to explain how it is possible that the user will ask for a list of users or a list of buckets and something useful would be done with the response, which would contain dramatically heterogenous objects.

Comment: But assuming that were true, you don't need a "giant switch" -- just an object.  `const operations = { 's3_list_bucket_contents': function(arg1, arg2, argN, cb) { s3.listObjects( ..., cb) }, ... };` then you can `var str = 's3_list_bucket_contents';` and then `operations[str](arg, ...);` and let the lookup of the desired function using the `str` key be your case/switch.  Your functions, the object values, can normalize the arguments as required by the specific SDK service/method.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: The method you propose is what I am using currently and I thought it was clunky. I am aware that the low level API access is more complex (not so complex for people who have written REST clients though), I had seen the signing requests page before. But, your `const operations ...` way is just another way of a giant `switch` statement and is just syntactically different. Anyway, that is "clunky" for me, but that is likely the only way.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: PS: I don't mean to call your solution a clunky one, I was just looking for something different, which in my world would be considered "elegant." 

I appreciate your help. Thank you!